# How to trigger animation once another animation starts in css

Tags: css, animation

I have an animation that plays when the image has the mouse hovered on it.

```
.zoomin img {

  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all .12s ease;

}
.zoomin img:hover {

-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.15) skew(0deg) translate(000px);
```

I have text under this image, and when the scale transform happens it blocks the text. how would I make animations trigger only when the hover animation triggers? I would like to push the text down when the animation plays

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your html code, but if your text is under your `<img>` tag, maybe you can use '+' selector to move your text, when image is hovered

```css
.zoomin img:hover + text {
# change properties to move your text, margin-top, transition, etc
}
```

or, if it will push your text down, you can increase margin-bottom of the image.